# while writing into typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python

I am new to python.When I want to build a linear regression model about a excel file,the code have some problem and can't run.what should I do tou solve it?

```
def linear_regression_by_gd(X, Y, gamma=0.000001, eps=0.0001, max_iter=100): 
    pre_w = np.array(np.ones((X.shape[1], 1)))
    cur_w = np.array(np.zeros((X.shape[1], 1)))
    count = 1
    while (cur_w - pre_w).T.dot(cur_w - pre_w) > eps and count < max_iter:
        pre_w = cur_w
        cur_w = cur_w - np.array(gamma / np.sqrt(count) * X.T.dot(X.dot(cur_w) - Y))
        count += 1
    return cur_w

w = linear_regression_by_gd(x_train, y_train)
```

Here is the full error information：

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 2001, in na_op
        result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 208, in evaluate
        return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 68, in _evaluate_standard
        return op(a, b)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/JetBrains/untitled/a/b.py", line 60, in <module>
        w = linear_regression_by_gd(x_train, y_train)
      File "D:/JetBrains/untitled/a/b.py", line 56, in linear_regression_by_gd
        cur_w = cur_w -np.array(gamma / np.sqrt(count) * X.T.dot(( X.dot(cur_w)) - (Y)))
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 2023, in f
        return self._combine_frame(other, pass_op, fill_value, level)
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5090, in _combine_frame
        result = _arith_op(this.values, other.values)
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5084, in _arith_op
        return func(left, right)
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 2003, in na_op
        result = masked_arith_op(x, y, op)
      File "D:\JetBrains\untitled\a\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1009, in masked_arith_op
        com.values_from_object(yrav[mask]))
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Pleas add the full error message and traceback to your question.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Full traceback please so we can identify the line, and *put it into your question, not as a comment*.  Will also need values for `x_train` and `y_train` - basically enough code to reproduce your problem and check that any solution works.

Comment: @soleilzxy That is just the error message which was already in your question title. Please also provide the *traceback*. That is the part that begins `Traceback (most recent call last):` and continues up to the error message.

Comment: @ BoarGules@cdarke Thank your advice very much andI will add the error message to the traceback to my question.

Comment: Can you also add a set of data which we can use to reproduce the error?

Comment: Python variables can be assigned values of any type, but once a value has been assigned it does have a type. The error suggests that `x_train` or `y_train` contains *string* values. Only a comment because without knowing what are `x_train` and `y_train` I cannot know how to coerce them to float.